# C# WPF xaml неправильное поведение ZIndex

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Не могу понять, почему элементы не накладываются друг на друга. Как можно это исправить? По логике вещей я каждому элементу, что находится выше задаю индекс больше, чем элементу ниже, но это не работает
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp4.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp4"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid >
        <ItemsControl HorizontalAlignment="Center"  VerticalAlignment="Center" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate  >
                    <Grid ZIndex="{Binding ZIndex}"  Cursor="Hand" Width="200"  >
                        <Grid.Triggers>
                            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard TargetName="label" TargetProperty="(Label.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                        <ColorAnimation To="Aqua" Duration="0:0:0.500"></ColorAnimation>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </EventTrigger>
                            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseLeave">
                                <EventTrigger.Actions >
                                    <BeginStoryboard  >
                                        <Storyboard TargetName="label" TargetProperty="(Label.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                            <ColorAnimation To="White" Duration="0:0:0.500"></ColorAnimation>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </BeginStoryboard>
                                </EventTrigger.Actions>
                            </EventTrigger>
                        </Grid.Triggers>
                        <Grid.RenderTransform>
                            <SkewTransform AngleY="-15"/>
                        </Grid.RenderTransform>

                        <Grid>
                            <Grid Width="200" Height="40" Background="green"    Margin="0 0 0 0">
                                <Grid.RenderTransform>
                                    <TransformGroup>
                                        <TranslateTransform Y="-40"  ></TranslateTransform>
                                        <SkewTransform AngleX="45" />
                                    </TransformGroup>
                                </Grid.RenderTransform>
                            </Grid>

                            <Grid  Background="Red" >
                                <Label Foreground="White" Name="label"   Padding="15"   Content="{Binding Name}"/>
                            </Grid>

                            <Grid Width="40" Background="#3e3f46"  RenderTransformOrigin="1 1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="-40 0 0 0">
                                <Grid.RenderTransform>
                                    <SkewTransform AngleY="45" />
                                </Grid.RenderTransform>
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfApp4
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Items.Add(new Data(){ ZIndex = 2, ZIndex2 = -10+1, Name = "HOME"});
            Items.Add(new Data() { ZIndex = 1, ZIndex2 = -9+1, Name = "ABOUT" });
            //Items.Add(new Data(){ ZIndex = 3, ZIndex2 = 4-1, Name = "SERVICES" });
            //Items.Add(new Data(){ ZIndex = 4, ZIndex2 = 3-1, Name = "PORTFOLIO" });
            //Items.Add(new Data(){ ZIndex = 5, ZIndex2 = 2-1, Name = "OUR TEAM" });
            //Items.Add(new Data(){ ZIndex = 6, ZIndex2 = 1-1, Name = "CONTACT" });
            DataContext = this;
        }

        public List<Data> Items { get; set; }= new List<Data>();
    }
    public struct Data
    {
        public int ZIndex { get; set; }
        public int ZIndex2 { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: `<Grid Panel.ZIndex="{Binding ZIndex}"`, вроде так надо

Comment: Без разницы, Grid наследуется от Panel

Comment: Вы попробовали? И наследование тут не при чем. `ZIndex` - это свойство самого грида, а `Panel.ZIndex` - это присоединенное свойство панели, в которой этот грид находится. Почитайте про присоединение свойства зависимости - attached `DependencyProperty`

Comment: Да, я попробовал, ничего не изменилось. И у грида нет своего ZIndex, оно есть только у панели, а грид наследуется от этой самой панели. Это можно увидеть в сурсах

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```xml
<ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style>
        <Setter Property="Panel.ZIndex" Value="{Binding ZIndex}"/>
    </Style>
</ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
```

И можно убрать `ZIndex` у грида. Смысл здесь в том, что сам грид напрямую не лежит в стекпанели, он лежит в контент-презентере, поэтому играть индексами внутри контейнера где кроме единственного грида ничего нет, сами понимаете.

```
Items.Add(new Data() { ZIndex = 6, Name = "HOME" });
Items.Add(new Data() { ZIndex = 5, Name = "ABOUT" });
Items.Add(new Data() { ZIndex = 4, Name = "SERVICES" });
Items.Add(new Data() { ZIndex = 3, Name = "PORTFOLIO" });
Items.Add(new Data() { ZIndex = 2, Name = "OUR TEAM" });
Items.Add(new Data() { ZIndex = 1, Name = "CONTACT" });
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо, это помогло =)